# Gems not found because installed in different locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some gems that are not being found b/c I think they are installed in the wrong location. How can I fix this? My setup:

```
which gem allure-cucumber
/Users/qahq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem

which gem cucumber
/Users/qahq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem
/Users/qahq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@idme-revelator/bin/cucumber

rvm gemset name
idme-revelator

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/qahq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@idme-revelator
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/qahq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/qahq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@idme-revelator/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/qahq/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/qahq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/qahq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@idme-revelator
     - /Users/qahq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/qahq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@idme-revelator/bin
     - /Users/qahq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin
     - /Users/qahq/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
     - /Users/qahq/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin

allure
-bash: allure: command not found
```

I'm guessing the `allure` command isn't working b/c it's not in the proper directory that `cucumber` is in, b/c the `cucumber` command works.

How can I fix this?

Comment: run `bundle install` from the rails app; that should place all the required gems in a single place.

Comment: What happens when you run `bundle install`?

Comment: It just lists all the gems..."Using abc gem" "Using def gem" etc...

Comment: Read up on bundler. http://softwarebymatt.com/blog/intro-to-bundler/ is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with `bundle exec rails server`